# Dynamic image scaling

Tags: html, css, image

Is dynamic imagescaling a CSS function or HTML code?

Comment: What do you mean by image scaling? What's your source?  What are you wanting in the end? describe your problem.

Comment: There's not enough detail in your question. CSS(2) cannot generally scale images "dynamically". Images can be scaled in HTML with `<img width="smaller than actual width" height="smaller than actual width" />`. However, you're most likely talking about something which uses javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to change the size of an image through JavaScript.

```
img.style.width = "123px";
img.style.height = "321px";
```

Answer (score 1):

Note sure what you mean, but you can use percentage instead of pixels, f.x. only using width the images will dynamically resize itself with its container and keep its aspect ratio.

So I would say your looking for a css styling to do what you want to do. But I need more info to understand what your trying to do.